# Generate bank account balance in Oracle table

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have an accounts table and a movements table in an Oracle 11g database. They work the way you would expect your bank account to work. A simplified version of them would be

```
CREATE TABLE accounts (
    id NUMERIC(20) NOT NULL -- PK
);

CREATE TABLE movements (
    id NUMERIC(20) NOT NULL, -- PK
    account_id NUMERIC(20) NOT NULL, -- FK to accounts table
    stamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, -- Movement creation timestamp
    amount NUMERIC(20) NOT NULL,
    balance NUMERIC(20) NOT NULL
);
```

You have an account, and some movements are secuentially created, each with a given amount. For example, I would expect the following data to be in the `movements` table:

```
| id | account_id |       stamp         |  amount | balance |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|  1 |     1      | 2016-12-29 00:00:01 |   50.00 |   50.00 |
|  2 |     1      | 2016-12-29 00:00:02 |   80.00 |  130.00 |
|  3 |     1      | 2016-12-29 00:00:03 |  -15.00 |  115.00 |
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

My problem is, how do I keep the `balance` column updated?

I'm doing the inserts inside a Stored Procedure (`INSERT INTO movements ... SELECT FROM ...`), so it can be done either inside the same query, in a later `UPDATE`, or with pure PLSQL.

I can think of two methods:

1. An `UPDATE` after the insert, something like (an idea, not tested):

   ```
   UPDATE movements um
   SET balance = (um.amount + (SELECT m.balance
                            FROM movements m
                            WHERE m.account_id = um.account_id
                              AND rownum = 1
                            ORDER BY stamp DESC)) -- last balance from same account?
   WHERE stamp > :someDate; -- To limit the updated records
   ```

   My problem with this is, does it executes in order? From the first movement to the last? Or oracle might run this without specific order, generating the scenario where, for example, the third movement gets updated before the second, so the balance from the second is still outdated?
2. Cursors: I could define a cursor and run a loop on the ordered list of movements, reading the previous balance of the account in each iteration, and calculating the current balance, setting it with an `UPDATE`.

   This way I would be certain that the balances are updated in order, but I've always avoided cursors because of the performance issues. This stored procedure will work with hundreds of records each time, and the movements table will store millions of records. Will the performance become an issue this way?

**My final question would be, considering performance, what is the best way to generate the `balance` column data?**

### Edit - Clarification on movements creation

I think I wasn't too clear about this part. At the moment of my SP execution, I'm creating several movements of several different accounts, that's why I mention that the movements creation is done with something like

```
-- Some actions

INSERT INTO movements (account_id, stamp, amount, balance)
SELECT ... FROM several_tables_with_joins;

-- More actions
```

That's why I mention that the balance could be generated either in the same query, in a later `UPDATE` or some other method like the Trigger mentioned in one of the comments.

Comment: `Trigger` after insert or update is the solution

Comment: And in the trigger query the last `balance` of the account? It won't be too heavy?

Comment: This won't work in a multi-user environment. What if two users enter different transactions for the same account *almost* at the same time? Neither is aware of the other transaction at the time they start entering their own. You will need to serialize the transactions, and your users will hate you for it. Better to create a view that computes the balance on the fly (then perhaps make it a MV with fast refresh on commit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> " considering performance, what is the best way to generate the balance column data"

Usually the ongoing maintenance of summed columns after every transaction incurs a heavier cost than simply calculating them on demand. However, account balance is a special case, because we do need to know it after every transaction, to check, say, whether the account has gone into the red or exceeded an overdraft limit.

The key insight is: before we process a new movement *we already know know the current balance*. It's the value of BALANCE for the latest MOVEMENT record.

Ah, but how do we know which MOVEMENT record is the latest? There are various different solutions to this, but the simplest would be an ugly `is_latest` flag. This not only provides a simple way to get the most recent MOVEMENT record it provides a lockable target, which is important in a multi-user environment. We need to ensure that only one transaction is manipulating the balance at any given time.

So, your stored procedure will look something like:

```
create or replace procedure new_movement 
   ( p_account_id in movements.account_id%type
     , p_amount in movements.amount%type )
is
    cursor c_curr_bal (p_acct_id movements.account_id%type) is
        select balance 
        from movements
        where account_id = p_acct_id
        and is_latest = 'Y'
        for update of is_latest; 
    l_balance movements.balance%type;
    new_rec movements%rowtype;
begin
    open c_curr_bal(p_account_id);
    fetch c_curr_bal into l_balance;

    new_rec.id := movements_seq.nextval;
    new_rec.account_id := p_account_id;
    new_rec.stamp := systimestamp;
    new_rec.amount := p_amount;
    new_rec.balance := l_balance + p_amount;
    new_rec.is_latest := 'Y';

    update movements
    set is_latest = null
    where current of c_curr_bal;

    insert into movements
    values new_rec;    

    close c_curr_bal;

    commit; -- need to free the lock
end new_movement;
/
```

---

An alternative to the `is_latest` flag would be to maintain the current balance as a column on the ACCOUNTS table. The logic would be the same, just SELECT the ACCOUNTS table FOR UPDATE OF CURRENT_BALANCE instead.

Comment: What sentence is locking the `is_latest` record? The `update`? Then shouldn't it be at the begining, before the last `balance` value is read? Also, please look at my edit in the question.

Comment: The SELECT FOR UPDATE issues a lock on the `balance` record. So it is locked at the start of the transaction, when the cursor is opened.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would keep the BALANCE in the ACCOUNTS table. Then when you insert your MOVEMENTS record, you update the corresponding ACCOUNT record.